# How to write iptables rule to accept certain ICMPv6 types and codes?

Tags: iptables

I currently have the following:

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp --icmpv6-type 1 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp --icmpv6-type 2 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp --icmpv6-type 3 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp --icmpv6-type 4 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp --icmpv6-type 128 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp --icmpv6-type 129 -j ACCEPT
```

For ICMPv6 type 3, I would like to only accept code 0.

For ICMPv6 type 4, I would like to only accept codes 1 and 2.

This is based on [RFC 4890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4890#section-4.3.1).

Comment: "_This is based on RFC 4890._" You are only wanting to allow that which should not be dropped. What about "_Traffic That Normally Should Not Be Dropped_," such as Type 3 Code 1 and Type 4 Code 0? Normally, you would not drop any code in Types 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The man page for iptables-extensions(8) says:

```
   icmp6 (IPv6-specific)
       This extension can be used if  `--protocol  ipv6-icmp'  or  `--protocol
       icmpv6' is specified. It provides the following option:

       [!] --icmpv6-type type[/code]|typename
              This  allows  specification  of  the ICMPv6 type, which can be a
              numeric ICMPv6 type, type and code, or one of  the  ICMPv6  type
              names shown by the command
               ip6tables -p ipv6-icmp -h
```

Comment: So is it like `ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp --icmpv6-type 3[0] -j ACCEPT` or `ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp --icmpv6-type 3[/0] -j ACCEPT` or even `ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp --icmpv6-type 3/0 -j ACCEPT` Thanks